# Unable To Read XML Array If Array Has Parent Tag

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

XML file:

```
<AttackPattern>
  <AttackPatternLeft>
    <Pattern>
      <Player Id="GK">
        <PositionX>0.0</PositionX>
        <PositionY>0.0</PositionY>
      </Player>
      <Player Id="DL">
        <PositionX>0.0</PositionX>
        <PositionY>1.0</PositionY>
      </Player>
      <Player Id="DR">
        <PositionX>0.0</PositionX>
        <PositionY>2.0</PositionY>
      </Player>
      <Player Id="MDFL">
        <PositionX>0.0</PositionX>
        <PositionY>3.0</PositionY>
      </Player>
      <Player Id="MDFR">
        <PositionX>0.0</PositionX>
        <PositionY>4.0</PositionY>
      </Player>
    </Pattern>
  </AttackPatternLeft>
</AttackPattern>
```

TeamContainer.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[XmlRoot("AttackPattern")]
public class TeamContainer
{
```

what should I need to write here so i can go forward in XML by approching the child array or element of AttackPatternLeft

```
    //[XmlElement("AttackPatternLeft")]
    [XmlArray("Pattern")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Player")]
    public List<Team> listTeam = new List<Team> ();

    // Use this for initialization
    public static TeamContainer Load(string path) 
    {

        TextAsset lobjTextAssetXML = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(TeamContainer));

        StringReader reader = new StringReader (lobjTextAssetXML.text);
        TeamContainer lobjTeamContainer = serializer.Deserialize (reader) as TeamContainer;

        reader.Close();

        return lobjTeamContainer;
    }
}
```

TeamLoader.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class TeamLoader : MonoBehaviour {

public const string path = "AttackPattern";
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    TeamContainer lobjTeamContainer = TeamContainer.Load (path);

    //print ("check->"+ lobjTeamContainer.listTeam.Count);
    foreach (Player lobjPlayer in lobjTeamContainer.listTeam) {
        print ("------------------------");
        print (lobjPlayer.strID);
        print (lobjPlayer.fPositionX);
        print (lobjPlayer.fPositionY);

    }

  }
```

}

If I remove the tag `<AttackPatternLeft>` from the XML file I am able to read the Pattern array in XML, but cant read it when I make pattern array as a child of `<AttackPatternLeft>` element

Comment: Do you get an exception? If you serialize an instance of TeamContainer into XML (and the Pattern collection contains some data), does the resulting XML file take the form as above? (Maybe verify all you have correct attributes on all serializable properties?)

Comment: No I am not getting any exception error. I am just unable to get the pattern array when pattern array has parent tag <AttackPatternLeft>. If I remove that line I am able to read the XML.....here are my other file code to load and display XML added in a above question comment

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the following set of classes:

```
[XmlRoot("AttackPattern")]
public class TeamContainer
{
    public AttackPatternLeft AttackPatternLeft { get; set; }
}

public class AttackPatternLeft
{
    [XmlArray("Pattern")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Player")]
    public List<Player> Team { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public decimal PositionX { get; set; }
    public decimal PositionY { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```